# Multiple lines of text in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, listviewitem

I'm trying to get multiple lines in a listView I currently have the following XAML:

```
        <ListView x:Name="listTasks" Margin="0,0,1.5,0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding TasksCollection}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                            Value="{x:Null}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                            Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                            Value="{x:Null}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                            Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50px" />
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="CustomHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CustomHeaderStyle}">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding  StringFormat=" Module: {0} Conditions: {1}|{2}|{3} for {4} minutes">
                                        <Binding Path="Module"/>
                                        <Binding Path="FirstValue"/>
                                        <Binding Path="SecondValue"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ThirdValue"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Minutes"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

This outputs something like:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is something like this (ignore the different colored background):

[image]

I can't seem to bring my head around how I would do this, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a vertical `StackPanel` in order to put a series of `TextBlock` elements one on top of another:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Module, StringFormat='Module: {0}'}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstValue, StringFormat='Module: {0}'}"/>
      ...
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Or you can format everything in one `TextBlock':

```
<DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock>
      <Run Text="Module: "/><Run Text="{Binding Module}"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="Conditions: "/><Run Text="{Binding FirstValue}"/><LineBreak/>
      ...
   </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This isn't related to text wrapping, I need to change my code so it has one binded textblock on each line

Comment: @Sandeep - Sorry, misunderstood your question. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for some reason didn't think it would be that easy.